# C# Compiler for Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

Does anyone know how I can get the following code to compile in C#.  I keep getting errors no matter what I try.  I listed the errors down below.  Thanks for any help.

```
using System;

interface InterfaceA { void doA(); } 

class A : InterfaceA { public virtual void doA() {Console.WriteLine("Class A");} }

interface InterfaceB { void doB(); }

class B : InterfaceB { public virtual void doB(){ Console.WriteLine("Class B");}}

class C : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{  
   static void doA(A x) { x.doA(); }
   static void doB(B x) { x.doB(); } 

  public static void main()
  {
    A _a = new A();
    B _b = new B();
    doA(_a);   
    doB(_b);
  }

}
//Errors:
//'C' does not implement interface member InterfaceA.doA()
//'C' does not implement interface member InterfaceB.doB()
```

Comment: In class C, doA and doB should not be static. Static methods cannot implement interfaces.

Comment: -1. `doA(A x)` has nothing to do with `InterfaceA.doA()`

Comment: @dmitry - `class C` declares that it implements InterfaceA, but it does not implement doA().

Comment: Making doA(A x) not static will not solve the problem. And your answer says it does.

Comment: Since OP states that his problem is the specified compiler errors, they will be gone. We can only make guesses about what he tries to accomplish, so the answers could be different.

Comment: No they will not. That is the problem with your answer. `class C : InterfaceA
{  
   void doA(A x) { x.doA(); }}` still does not implement `interface InterfaceA { void doA(); }`

Comment: I'm trying to compile the exact code bit I posted and those are the errors I receive.

Comment: @dmitry, oh , now I see it. Then they should get rid of parameter as whell.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you are not implementing the interface methods in C class. Either remove the implementation.

Change code 
`class C : InterfaceA, InterfaceB` to `class C`
(which you most probably meant)

or implement interface methods in C class too as you have done in A and B.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

interface InterfaceA { void doA(); } 

class A : InterfaceA { public virtual void doA() {Console.WriteLine("Class A");} }

interface InterfaceB { void doB(); }

class B : InterfaceB { public virtual void doB(){ Console.WriteLine("Class B");}}

class C 
{
   static void doA(A x) { x.doA(); }
   static void doB(B x) { x.doB(); } 

  static void Main()
  {
    A _a = new A();
    B _b = new B();
    doA(_a);   
    doB(_b);
  }

}
```

Comment: When I try to compile this code, it gives me the same two errors I initially got.

Comment: @KevenDiuliy Don't lie to me. It works fine

Comment: Did you try to compile it.  I'm not lying.

Comment: I wish this would work, but it just doesn't.  Errors: "Class C does not implement interface member InterfaceA.doA() and same for InterfaceB.doB()

Comment: @KevenDiuliy - Did you notice that Dmitry _removed_ the interface declarations from class C?  (i. e. `class C` instead of `class C : InterfaceA, InterfaceB` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 interface InterfaceA { void doA(); }

    class A : InterfaceA { public virtual void doA() { Console.WriteLine("Class A"); } }

    interface InterfaceB { void doB(); }

    class B : InterfaceB { public virtual void doB() { Console.WriteLine("Class B"); } }

    class C : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            A _a = new A();
            B _b = new B();
           _a.doA();
            _b.doB();
        }

        public void doA()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void doB()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Your method signatures do not match the interface, hence the error. And you are using static and not public.

Comment: When I try to compile this code it says it does not contain a static "Main" method suitable for an entry point.  Why is that?

Comment: may be because the class c is private

Comment: you're right, it's been a while wrote those console apps

Answer (score -1):

You can't implement interfaces with static methods.